# css column layout middle column shows same height as right column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row

I have 3 columns: left, right, middle.  Can't seem to figure out how to prevent the middle column from displaying full height of the right column when I add a

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

to use columns inside of it.  Being that the class .row (bootstrap) in it's :before and :after has "display:table" then that causes that div to go full height of the right column and whatever text that comes after that row goes way at the bottom.  Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3a9yuwx/1/)

but just in case here's the basic code, there's really nothing advanced about it.

```css
.container{
    height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.leftcolumn{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background:yellow;
}

.rightcolumn{
    float:right;
    width:150px;
    background:red;
}

.middlecolumn{
    margin:0 160px 0 110px;
    background:green;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use `float:left` on `.leftcolumn`, `float:right` on `.rightcolumn` and then you position the middle one through `margins`? 
That doesn't look right to me. How about floating all three of them or using `display: inline-block`?
BTW, `display: inline-block` would also help if you set it on `.row` but I'd avoid that since it's basically hacking Bootstrap.

Comment: i'm working with sass so hacking bootstrap is not an issue but putting display:inline-block on a clear float doesn't work. and using inline-blocks for the columns doesn't work either since i need the middle column to cover full width of page except the size of side columns

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code by let the middlecolumn float with the others two.

This way you just have to adjust some margin to center it horizontally.

You can find the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k3a9yuwx/2/)

The best solution to get the wanted result is using bootstrap grid system. You can wrap you columns inside a row and push/pull them with the proper classes. I.E. `col-xs-offset-4` or `col-xs-push-4` will move your element 4 columns to the right, so you can position all your columns

Comment: yea i wanted to use bootstrap grid system for the main columns but unfortunantly those i have to do by hand because they want it to be a specific size.  and I saw that this fixed the height issue in the middle column but the width now is not the full remaining with? what i kinda need is the middle column to cover full width except the sizes of left and right columns?